# Group Action as permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to study on Group actions. the paper says(if I understand) that if I have Set $S$ and an action $\alpha$: $G \times S \rightarrow S$ . 
then the action may be viewed as permutation by $x \rightarrow \alpha(g,x)$.

The thing is after reading the definition I can't see why it is not possible that $\alpha(g,x_1) = \alpha(g,x_2) $ where $x_1 \neq x_2$ , and thus we don't have a permutation.

your help is appropriated

Comment: Could you add any reference to the cited paper?

Comment: well, the word paper was not the correct word to use... I have copy of some pages of a book. if you read from wiki you can see it is almost trivial assertion - that's is basically what I have in the page(quote from wiki) : "If G is a group and X is a set, then a group action may be defined as a group homomorphism h from G to the symmetric group on X. The action assigns a permutation of X to each element of the group in such a way that the permutation of X assigned to"  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose that what your reference is saying is that an action **induces** for every $g \in G$ a **permutation** on $S$ defined by the mapping 
$$x \mapsto \alpha(g,x)\ ,$$
where $g$ is fixed.

This mapping is indeed a permutation because it has an inverse, namely the mapping defined as 
$$x \mapsto \alpha(g^{-1},x)\ .$$

If you call the first mapping $\varphi_g$ and the second one $\varphi_{g^{-1}}$ a simple computation shows that for every $x \in S$
$$\varphi_{g^{-1}}(\varphi(g))=\alpha(g^{-1},\alpha(g,x))=\alpha(g^{-1}g,x)=\alpha(1,x)=x$$
where the last equalities follow from the definition of action of a group.

The mapping that associates to every $g \in G$ the permutation $\varphi_g$ is an homomorphism from $G$ to the group $\text{Aut}(S)$, the group of permutation of $S$.

The converse also holds: for every $\varphi \colon G \to \text{Aut}(S)$ you obtain the mapping 
$$\alpha \colon G \times S \to S$$
defined by $\alpha(g,x)=\varphi_g(x)$.
With some easy computations you can prove that, since $\varphi$ is an homomorphism, $\alpha$ is indeed an action of $G$ on $S$.

This is actually a very common phenomena in mathematics: usually to every kind of algebraic structure (monoid, group, ring, algebra) is associated a notion of action which turns out to be equivalent to the notion of an homomorphism from the structure to a structure made out of endo/auto-morphisms.

Also if you know about currying then an action can be defined as the uncurried version of an homomorphism into an endomorphism structure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

$\alpha(g,x_1) = \alpha(g,x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$, since by the [definition of a group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Definition)

$$
\alpha(g^{-1},\alpha(g,x)) = \alpha(g^{-1}g,x)=\alpha(e,x)=x\;.
$$